# How to render lines between visible and invisible points?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, glm-math

I'm trying to implement rendering of a screen projection of a grid using opencv drawing utils to figure out, how it actually works. However, I have a problem with drawing lines when one point is supposed to be on and the other off screen.

As visibility criteria I'm using `v4.w > 0`.

If both points are required to be visible to draw a line, the line disappears when one of the points is too far behind camera. (Left - rendered with opengl, how it should look, right - how it looks, rendered with my code)

[image: right - rendered with opengl, how it should look, left - how it looks, rendered with my code]

And if only one point is required to be on screen it's a complete mess.

[image]

The code:

```
    glm::mat4 calc_MVP(const glm::mat4 & ViewMatrix, const glm::mat4 & ProjectionMatrix)
    {
        double scale_factor = 10;

//          First let's store our scale in a 3d vector:
        glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(scale_factor, scale_factor, scale_factor);

//          Now we need a basic model matrix with no transformations:
        glm::mat4 ModelMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0);

        glm::mat4 TranslationMatrix = translate(mat4(), glm::vec3(-5.f, 0.0f, -5.f));

        ModelMatrix = TranslationMatrix * ModelMatrix;

//      Now we can apply the scale to our model matrix:
        ModelMatrix = glm::scale(ModelMatrix, scale);

        return ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix * ModelMatrix;
    }


    void draw(const glm::mat4 & ViewMatrix, const glm::mat4 & ProjectionMatrix, cv::Mat & frame)
    {
        const glm::mat4 MVP = calc_MVP(ViewMatrix, ProjectionMatrix);

        const cv::Size size = frame.size();
        const int frame_w = size.width;
        const int frame_h = size.height;

        std::vector<cv::Point2d> points;
        std::vector<bool> visible;

        for (const glm::vec3 & v3 : vertices){
            glm::vec4 v4 = {v3.x, v3.y, v3.z, 1};
            v4 = MVP * v4;
            cv::Point2d p;

            p.x = v4.x / v4.w * frame_w / 2 + frame_w / 2;
            p.y = frame_h - (v4.y / v4.w * frame_h / 2 + frame_h / 2);

            visible.push_back(v4.w > 0);
            points.push_back(p);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < indices.size(); i += 1){
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
                int indx1 = indices[i][j];
                int indx2 = indices[i][(j + 1) % 4];

                cv::Point2d p1 = points[indx1];
                cv::Point2d p2 = points[indx2];

                if (visible[indx1] and visible[indx2])
                {
                    cv::line(frame, p1, p2, clr, 2, 1);
                } else if (visible[indx1]){
//                  cv::line(frame, p1, p2, clr, 2, 1);
                } else if (visible[indx2]){
//                  cv::line(frame, p1, p2, clr, 2, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++i){
            if (visible[i])
                cv::circle(frame, points[i], 2, {255, 0, 0}, 2, 1);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to properly implement this?

Comment: You need to implement [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(computer_graphics)) against the view frustum. The idea is simple, but a 3D implementation requires a solid understanding of homogeneous coordinates and the projection transform.